# ThreeJS: InstancedMesh triangle count not updating

Tags: three.js

Say., I have a InstancedMesh with triangle count of 1000. When I move all the object/ instances out from the scene the triangles counts are remained to 1000 and when I zoom in to some particular set of instances the triangles counts remains the same all the time. But when I use Mesh and render the object the counts varies when in zoom in/out and the count will be 0 when the objects are not present in scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because view frustum culling is disabled by default for `InstancedMesh`. This is done because it's more complicated to compute bounding volumes for `InstancedMesh` than for `Mesh`. There is already a github issue that tracks this topic:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18334

Comment: Could you please suggest me this one for difference between InstanceMesh and Mesh? @Mugen87 Why can't I load transformation datas in interleavedbuffer and I'll handle it using shaders, why should I use matrix.setMatrixData. What is the major difference and performance impact in rendering in Mesh rather than InstancedMesh. I hope this should happens in the background too. Is the intancedMesh is for user accessibility? or it influences something in performance?

Comment: Um, it seems to me I've already answered you this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770265/difference-and-uses-of-instancedmesh-and-interleavedbuffer-in-threejs